# Storing Values in An array through multiple prepare for segue methods

Tags: swift

I have an array declared but not defined in a class (called Filteredoptions). I have another class that use the prepare for segue to add values to that array. In Filteredoption's viewdidload I print out all the values in the array, but the array only holds the value by whichever value was send the last. I tried appending to array but that also does not work. How can I fix this?

```
 class FilterOption: UIViewController {
var filter_saved:[String] = []
var filter_rec:[String] = []
//Filter type to send to Filter_IO
var Filter_type_tosend:String?
//Filtered Selection Values recieved from Filter_IO
//Button Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var SM_Outlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Followers_Outlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Views_Outlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Country_Outlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var State_Outlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var City_Outlet: UIButton!

//Button Actions
@IBAction func SM_Action(_ sender: Any) {
Filter_type_tosend = "Social_Media"
}
@IBAction func Followers_Action(_ sender: Any) {
Filter_type_tosend = "Followers"
}
@IBAction func Views_Action(_ sender: Any) {
Filter_type_tosend = "Views"
}
@IBAction func Country_Action(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func Apply_Changes_Action(_ sender: Any) {

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Filter_Option"{
        let destination = segue.destination as! Filter_IO
        destination.filter_type = Filter_type_tosend
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    for x in filter_rec{
        print(x)
        if x != nil{
            filter_saved.append(x)
        }
    }
    print("______________")

    print("filter saved")
    print("..............")
    for y in filter_saved{
        print(y)

    }
    print("-------------*****************")
    print("-------------*****************")
    print("-------------*****************")
    print("-------------*****************")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

```
  class Filter_IO: UIViewController {
//picker view variables
var picker_view_data:[String?] = []
var picker_view_selected_row:String?
var ROW:Any?
//Variable storing which Filter Option has been selected:
var filter_type:String?
@IBOutlet weak var Title_Outlet: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var Info_Outlet: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var Selection_Outlet: UIPickerView!

//Actions
@IBAction func Save_Changes_Action(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "save_changes_filter", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "save_changes_filter"{
        let dest = segue.destination as! FilterOption
        if picker_view_selected_row != nil{
            if filter_type != nil{
                switch filter_type as! String{
                case "Social_Media":
                    dest.filter_rec.append(picker_view_selected_row as! String)
                case "Followers":
                     dest.filter_rec.append("\(ROW as! Int)")
                case "Views":
                      dest.filter_rec.append("\(ROW as! Int)") 
                default:
                    print("filter error line 45 Filter_IO.swift ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if filter_type != nil{
        switch filter_type as! String {
            case "Social_Media":
                Title_Outlet.text = "Social_Media"
                 Selection_Outlet.delegate = self
                picker_view_data = ["Any", "Instagram", "Twitter", "Facebook", "Youtube"]
            case "Followers":
                Title_Outlet.text = "Followers"
                Selection_Outlet.delegate = self
                picker_view_data = ["Any", "0 to 500", "500-1k", "1k-5k", "5k-10k", "10k-50k", "50k-100k", "100k-500k", "500k-1M", "1M-2M", "2M-5M", "5M-10M", ">10M" ]
            case "Views":
                Title_Outlet.text = "Views/Likes"
                Selection_Outlet.delegate = self
                picker_view_data = ["Any", "0 to 500", "500-1k", "1k-5k", "5k-10k", "10k-50k", "50k-100k", "100k-500k", "500k-1M", "1M-2M", "2M-5M", "5M-10M", ">10M" ]

            default:
                Title_Outlet.text = "error"

        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



//MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate Implimentation.
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{
    plotMarker(AtCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 17.432699, longitude: 78.374674),onMapView: mapView)
}
//MARK: Plot Marker Helper
private func plotMarker(AtCoordinate coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D, onMapView vwMap : GMSMapView) -> Void
{
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    marker.map = vwMap
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
 }    extension Filter_IO: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
   return 1
   }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
    numberOfRowsInComponent . 
   component: Int) -> Int {
         return picker_view_data.count
      }
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, 
       forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       return picker_view_data[row]
      }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, 
  inComponent component: Int) {
    picker_view_selected_row = picker_view_data[row]
      ROW = row
   }

       }
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we won't be able to help

Comment: It was more of a general question but I just the added the code I was using. Thanks!